# StreamReader from remote server

Tags: c#

I am reading a large text file from a remote server (arnd 9gb).

When reading the file from remote server, the code is missing a large amount of the file and completing. When I move the file to the local server and read from there, it reads the entire file with no issues.

example:

```
Dictionary<string, string> NewFile = new Dictionary<string, string>();

string File = @"\\filesystem1\fileshare\rs\" + Session["Region"].ToString() + ".csv";

using (StreamReader str = new StreamReader(File, Encoding.ASCII))
      {
           string toread;
           while ((toread = str.ReadLine()) != null) //str.Peek() >= 0)
              {
                 //string[] line = str.ReadLine().Split(',');
                 string[] line = toread.Split(',');
                 NewFile.Add(line[2], line[0]);
               }
       }
```

Any ideas what could be causing the read to skip lines when reading from a server? The file should actually have about 250k entries but my var usually loads about 75k.

Regards

Comment: Investigate. Are the last lines missing, or does it happen all over the place? Are there incomplete lines?

Comment: Its just the end of the file. Reads first 75k then stops. Works fine if file is local and have checked the file at the line it stops - cant see any problem

Comment: @user1156000 What data is on the line it stops at? Your code specifies lines that aren't null - have you been to that line? Perhaps there is an empty one there.

Comment: Nope, I checked that looks fine. Also wouldnt explain why it runs with the file on local drive.

Comment: Have you tried using `File.ReadAllLines` instead? This is not an exact  equivalent to what you are trying to do (it is more taxing to memory), but would be illuminating to see if it fails too. If it does fail, try copying the file using Windows Explorer to see if you get the whole file - maybe this is some weird network problem? Or you just used the wrong path?